# Backbone.js comparator function isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using the following code in oder to make sure Models are added to a Collection based on their `created_at` unix time. Newer items should be before older.

```
comparator: function(a, b) {
    var time_a = a.get('created_at_time');
    var time_b = b.get('created_at_time');

    if(time_a < time_b) return -1;
    else if(time_a > time_b) return 1;
    else return 0; // time_a === time_b
}
```

For some reasons, items are returned in the wrong order anyway. Any thoughts on a solution? I'm using Backbone.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Backbone.Collection.comparator() doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator)

> Comparator function can be defined as either a sortBy (pass a function that takes a single argument), or as a sort (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments).

I think in your case is better if you go for the *sortBy* solution:

```
comparator: function( model ) {
  return model.get('created_at_time');
}
```

If you want the *reverse* order just use the numerical version multiplied by `-1`.

#### Updated

Anyhow your code was working properly, check the [working jsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/QEqzy/), so maybe the issue is somewhere else.